# UTC offset subtracted from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value in HSQLDB

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone, hsqldb, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using HSQLDB 2.4.0 and seeing unexpected `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values being returned.

I am running the following code with a JVM time zone of UTC+2

```
try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
             "SELECT '1960-01-01 23:03:20+02:00' "
           + "FROM (VALUES(0))");
     ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

  OffsetDateTime expected = OffsetDateTime.parse("1960-01-01T23:03:20+02:00");
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    assertEquals(expected, resultSet.getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class));
    assertEquals("1960-01-01 23:03:20+02:00", resultSet.getObject(1, String.class));
  }
}
```

The second assertion succeeds but the first fails. Instead of the expected `1960-01-01T23:03:20+02:00` value I get `1960-01-01T21:03:20+02:00` which is two hours before the expected value. Is this a bug or the expected behaviour?

**edit**

After some more investigation it seems that not the UTC offset of the local time zone but the UTC offset of the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` gets subtracted.

If I change `'1960-01-01 23:03:20+02:00'` to `CAST('1960-01-01 23:03:20+02:00' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) + INTERVAL '2:00' HOUR TO MINUTE` I get `1960-01-01T21:03:20+02:00`. Similarly `'1960-01-01 23:03:20+05:00'` is five hours off but `CAST('1960-01-01 23:03:20+02:00' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) + INTERVAL '5:00' HOUR TO MINUTE` gives me `1960-01-01T21:03:20+05:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug that has been fixed for the next release. You can checkout the SVN /base/trunk code and compile with Gradle or Ant.